# Выполнение запроса очень тормозится на объединении с подзапросом

Tags: sql, запрос, firebird

Есть запрос

```
select
eq.ID, …, c_CALIBRATION_INTERVAL
 from EQUIPMENT eq
 left join LABORATORY l on l.id = eq.EQUIPMENT_LABORATORY_ID
 left join LABORATORY ld on ld.id = eq.LABORATORY_DOC_ID
 left join CERTIFICATE c on c.DEVICE_ID_CL = eq.ID
 and c.DISPLAY = 1 
  left join USERS_DATA u on u.ID = eq.EQUIPMENT_PARENT_USER_ID
  left join USERS_DATA ud on ud.ID = eq.USER_DOC_ID
    where eq.ARCHIVE in (1)
  and (((eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE < '06.02.2023' and not eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT <> -1)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT >= 0)  or (eq.COUNT_CERT_REQUIRE <> eq.COUNT_CERT))
  and ((eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE < '06.02.2023' and not eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT <> -1)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT >= 0)  or (eq.COUNT_CERT_REQUIRE <> eq.COUNT_CERT)))
  and ((c.CONTROL = 1 and eq.PASSPORT = 0) or ((c.CONTROL is null or c.CONTROL=1) and eq.PASSPORT = 1))
  order by eq.EQUIPMENT_PARENT_USER_ID, eq.NAME, eq.TYPE, eq.NUMBER, eq.NEMBER_INVENTORY
```

, но он работал чуть не правильно и пришлось его дополнить подзапросом, который я запихнул в *VIEW*:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW V_CERTIFICATE_SIGNAL(
    DEVICE_ID_CL,
    CERTIFICATE_ID)
AS
select gr0.DEVICE_ID_CL, (case when gr1.id is null then gr0.id else gr1.id end) as CERTIFICATE_ID
  from (select max(c.ID) as ID, c.DEVICE_ID_CL
          from CERTIFICATE c
            where c.CONTROL = 1
              group by c.DEVICE_ID_CL) gr0
  left join (select c.id, c.DEVICE_ID_CL
               from CERTIFICATE c
                 where c.CONTROL = 1 and c."DISPLAY" = 1) gr1 on gr0.DEVICE_ID_CL = gr1.DEVICE_ID_CL    ;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - Часть таблицы *CERTIFICATE*
Оба представленных запроса по отдельности работают быстро. Но когда я объединил первый запрос с *VIEW*, он начал **очень сильно тормозить**

```
select
eq.ID, eq.NAME,  eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE, eq."TYPE", eq.NUMBER, eq.NEMBER_INVENTORY, eq.PRODUCER, eq.YEAR_BEGIN, eq.NAME_TEST, eq.REMARK, eq.USER_ID,  eq.DEPARTMENT_ID, eq.TIME_EDIT,
 eq.ARCHIVE, eq.SPECIFICATION, eq.DEVICE_DEPARTMENT_ID, eq.TYPE_SERIES, eq.DISLOCATION, eq.TYPE_EQUIP, eq.PASSPORT, eq.WARNING,  eq.EQUIPMENT_LABORATORY_ID, eq.COUNT_CERT_REQUIRE,
 eq.CONTROL_MIN_DOC,  eq.EQUIPMENT_PARENT_USER_ID, eq.COUNT_CERT, l.NAME_SHORT as l_NAME_SHORT_LAB,   eq.LABORATORY_DOC_ID, eq.FIND_TALLY, eq.DISLOCATION_ORG, eq.USER_DOC_ID,
 u.FULL_NAME as u_EQUIPMENT_USER, ld.NAME_SHORT as l_LABORATORY_DOC, ud.FULL_NAME as u_USER_DOC
, (case when c.NUMBER_CERT = '-1' then '' else c.NUMBER_CERT end) as c_NUMBER_CERT,  c.DATE_OPERATION as c_DATE_OPERATION, c.CALIBRATION_INTERVAL as c_CALIBRATION_INTERVAL
 from EQUIPMENT eq
 left join LABORATORY l on l.id = eq.EQUIPMENT_LABORATORY_ID
 left join LABORATORY ld on ld.id = eq.LABORATORY_DOC_ID
 left join V_CERTIFICATE_SIGNAL vcs on vcs.DEVICE_ID_CL = eq.ID   -- "VIEW"
 left join CERTIFICATE c on vcs.CERTIFICATE_ID = c.ID
  left join USERS_DATA u on u.ID = eq.EQUIPMENT_PARENT_USER_ID
  left join USERS_DATA ud on ud.ID = eq.USER_DOC_ID
    where eq.ARCHIVE in (1)
  and (((eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE < '07.02.2023' and not eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT <> -1)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT >= 0)  or (eq.COUNT_CERT_REQUIRE <> eq.COUNT_CERT))
  and ((eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE < '07.02.2023' and not eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT <> -1)  or (eq.CONTROL_MIN_DATE is null and eq.COUNT_CERT >= 0)  or (eq.COUNT_CERT_REQUIRE <> eq.COUNT_CERT)))
  and ((c.CONTROL = 1 and eq.PASSPORT = 0) or ((c.CONTROL is null or c.CONTROL=1) and eq.PASSPORT = 1))
  order by eq.EQUIPMENT_PARENT_USER_ID, eq.NAME, eq.TYPE, eq.NUMBER, eq.NEMBER_INVENTORY
```

где-то 30 секунд выбирает 94 записи из возможных 344
Чуть поэкспериментировав, т.е. представил результат *VIEW*, в виде обычной таблицы, и подставив ее вместо *VIEW*, все прошло **быстро и без** тормозов.

Что можно посмотреть и куда копать, чтоб ускорить запрос с использованием *VIEW*?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вам обязательно нужно именно через VIEW? Хранимая процедура тут сработает лучше

Comment: нет необязательно, я хочу повысить скорость выполнения, если через процедуру это можно как-то сделать, то подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Мне просто нужно быстро вбрать этим view (или ка-нибудь еще, ну чтобы скорость не терялась), данные из таблицы CTRTIFICATE (см.рис.),

Comment: Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что у `view` нет индексов, по крайней мере в `firebird`, если я правильно понял документацию.

Comment: нет индекс есть по полю *ID*

Comment: @Konstantin78 В самом View есть индекс? Они там похоже не предусмотрены. Либо я чего-то не понял. Кстати, само View если его отдельно заселектить быстро выполняется?

Comment: да, я ошибся извиняюсь - не о том подумал

Comment: можно конечно в табл. *CERTIFICATE* добавить дополнительное поле (формировать в нем значение, например "1", чтоб не группировать), и тогда *VIEW* не нужно, просто использовать его в условии *join* - но как не хотелось бы(

Comment: А после `where` у вас много записей остаётся? Можно попробовать вынести этот `join` который с `view` и всё что дальше на него завязано в отдельный дополнительный запрос. Т.е. запросить сначала всё остальное по всем условиям, а потом к тому, что получится, уже заджойнить `view` и что там дальше на неё завязано. Но зависит от того, хорошая ли селективность у остального запроса.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да записей прилично, спасибо за подсказку - обдумаю. Но мне кажется любой *VIEW*/или использование дополнительный запрос (по сути тот же *VIEW*) - хорошо будет тормозить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE P_CERTIFICATE_SIGNAL(
    DEVICE_ID_CL INTEGER)
RETURNS(
    CERTIFICATE_ID INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  select first 1 с.id
  from CERTIFICATE c
  where c.CONTROL = 1 and c."DISPLAY" = 1
    and c.DEVICE_ID_CL = :DEVICE_ID_CL
  into :CERTIFICATE_ID  
    
  if (:CERTIFICATE_ID IS NULL) THEN
    select first 1 с.id
    from CERTIFICATE c
    where c.CONTROL = 1
      and c.DEVICE_ID_CL = :DEVICE_ID_CL
    order by с.id DESC  
    into :CERTIFICATE_ID  

  SUSPEND;
END
```

Мы сначала пытаемся найти ID вашим подзапросом gr1, и только если ничего не найдено, то подзапросом gr0.

Я писал из расчёта на то, что gr1 возвращает не больше одной записи.

Использование:

```
 ...
 left join LABORATORY ld on ld.id = eq.LABORATORY_DOC_ID
 left join P_CERTIFICATE_SIGNAL(eq.ID) vcs on 1 = 1 -- "PROCEDURE"
 left join CERTIFICATE c on vcs.CERTIFICATE_ID = c.ID
 ...
```

Comment: **Спасибо**  всем откликнувшимся, особенно *@Герман Борисов*. - помогло, **работает без** тормозов (надо будет запомнить "про процедуру")

Comment: @Konstantin78, это в принципе особенность Firebird, особенно ранних версий. Если нужно оптимизировать подзапрос — выноси в хранимку.